# Servlet/JSF: Pass parameter from filter to bean method invoked later

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

In my JSF application I have implemented a Filter class that redirects non-logged in requests to the login page.

Before I do the redirect, I store some parameters as attributes in the session object. I do this, so I can access them in RequestScoped beans when their methods are called on the login page.

Currently, I do it like this:

```
httpSession.setAttribute("parameterKey", "text");
```

And retrieve them in RequestScoped bean by doing:

```
String parameter = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("parameterKey");
```

It works, but I'm not happy with it. Is there a way to accomplish this without filling the session with some junk?

Comment: Add it as a requestparameter in the redirect and make sure in the post it is used again?

Comment: You are talking about the query string part of the URL, right? I can access it in the post by retrieving the "referer" header and then parse it by hand. Or is there a prettier way?

Comment: @Param annotations, or <f:viewparam....> Several options... Omnifaces can be of help too.